# XRDP access to ubuntu instance produces "Oh no! Something went wrong" for some users

Tags: xubuntu, remote-desktop, xrdp, aws

I am creating an EC2 AMI on AWS running Ubuntu 20.04 for a training workshop.
The initialization of this instance includes the following:

```
  apt -y install ubuntu-desktop
  DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt -y install xubuntu-desktop
  apt -y install xrdp
  systemctl status xrdp
  systemctl enable xrdp
  adduser xrdp ssl-cert
  systemctl restart xrdp
```

to install the ubuntu desktop and xrdp

While this works fine for me, one of my team reports that accessing through an RDP client immediately
gives the grey screen with "Oh no! Something has gone wrong" and gives no alternative but to log out altogether.

This is Ubuntu 20.04 last updated 2/10/21

Is there anything that I missed in the above instructions to ensure this doesn't happen?

Comment: On the affected instance(s), look for a .crash file in /var/crash. That will explain in very technical detail exactly what went wrong.

Comment: Had the same problem on my own account, fixed it via SSH with `echo startxfce4 > ~/.xsession`